# 400 amp meter base combo

Tags: electrical-panel

I plan on using a 400 amp meter base combo with a 200 amp QNR breaker for a 200 amp sub panel, a 100 amp QP breaker for a sub panel, a 70 amp QP breaker for a sub panel and a 20 amp AFCI/GFCI breaker for an outlet mounted on the meter rack. Are there any issues with this setup?

For clarification; I want to use a 200A breaker for main house panel.
100A breaker for guest house panel. 70A for well house/pool equipment panel and 20A for outside outlet. (can the 200A and 100A breakers feed (2) separate panels in the same dwelling?)

The combo panel is Siemens and comes with (1) 200A breaker that feeds the installed bus (which has feed through lugs). It also has a provision for another 200A breaker.

Question: Is there a requirement for the bus on this type of panel to have a dedicated breaker -OR- can the feed through lugs be used directly from the meter side to power the bus (as shown in the picture), then the breakers on the bus (100, 70, 20) used as disconnects for the respective panels/outlet? Can a breaker be used as a disconnect?

The reason I would not want to power the bus with a dedicated breaker is that in the event the VFD needs to cut power to the panels, they could still leave the well house powered and have use of the water.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Will there be a 400A main breaker somewhere?

Comment: What make and model is the meter-main you are planning to use? Also, what are these subpanels for?  This sounds like a pretty complicated setup...

Comment: No; There is no 400A breaker.

Comment: Siemens MC0816B1400RLTM  class 320 lever bypass  socket. Load center is provided a 200A main breaker and 8/16 interior w/ feed thru lugs. Space for +1 main breaker up to 200A. The 8/16 circuits inside the panel feed exterior loads also providing ability to feed up to 2 more load centers from this panel. 2nd main breaker is QNR type (150, 175, or 200 Amp) or QP double pole  (60, 70, 80, 90, 100, or 125 Amp). NEMA Type 3R  confirms to UL standard 50.

Comment: I take it that when you say "meter rack", you mean a dedicated support that has the metering and mains on it, located outside and away from any structures, with the underground utility lateral coming to it and feeders leading from it to the various buildings?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - you precisely described the "meter rack" and underground distribution.

Comment: @user96213 who is your utility?  Also, are you saying the ADU and main house are in the same structure, or do you want more than 200A for the main house by itself?

Comment: My utility is Bandera Electric (BEC), Bandera Texas. I would have 200A and 100A in the main house on separate panels at either end if I could do it  just easier for me the way the home is designed.

Comment: What is driving the need for more than 200A to the house? (Am I correct that the 200A and 100A breakers are feeding the same occupancy within the structure, and not something that has been split into say a main dwelling unit and an ADU?)

Comment: The architect specified 400A service based on square footage (upstairs/downstairs) of all electric home, 4 bed, 4 bath, A/C & Heat Pumps, dual ovens, range top, pool and spa, on demand hot water. And well water treatment, oversized garage/shop area, electric gates and exterior lighting. Plus room for growth of a planned ADU (guest house). That said, I can see that it might be reasonable to run the main house on 200A, and the ADU on 100A and the pool, well equipment and small shop on 100A. I am a year out from construction so am sorting this now.... –

Comment: "on demand hot water" -- there's half your problem right there.  Instantaneous electric water heaters are major current hogs, and really don't gain you much if anything over a modern tanked heater. (Today's electric tank heaters are good enough that most of the heat leakage left is via the pipes!)  Also, how many square feet are we looking at here, and how much tonnage of heat pump is being planned for ATM?

Comment: Concur on the "on demand" water heaters... total living is 3,500 + 1,000 garage that will have an a/c unit just to keep it bearable in the summer. Ceiling ht is 10' to 12' depending on room if that matters. I'll check on the heat pump sizing to be certain. Also forgot to mention electric car charging station; 40A (to 80A depending on type installation).

Comment: A/C; likely 5, 3.5 and 2 ton....

Comment: @user96213 -- so 5 tons for the main house, 3.5 tons for the ADU/guest house, and 2 tons for the garage?

Comment: Also, how many square feet is the guest house?

Comment: ADU will be in neighborhood of 1000sf.

Comment: utility stressed cost comparison of installation with 400 vs. 200 or 320A.  On site, there is currently overhead service on the property line. There is a single pole with transformer providing 200A service to a neighbor. Engineer stated the transformer would only supply 200A to either or both customers and if they are upgrading to not stop at a 320A transformer, rather go to 400A since that is what they offer - better to have it available vs. future cost to upgrade (again). There are several customers in the area paying for dual (2 meters) 200A service vs. a single 320 or 400A meter.

Comment: Am I over thinking this? Even if I "have" 400A available, it does not mean will be or need to be using it all straight away..... but it will be available for use if the need arises. Not related; utility is also selling customers on solar and (as of yet available in our neighborhood) broadband service; which I understand - sales and marketing.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel - any opportunity to chat about this offline? (I'm new here and don't want to break any rules or boundaries; apologies as required).

Comment: @user96213 -- note that a "true" 400A service requires different metering hardware vs. 320A (which is what your current choice of meter-main is designed for), either what's called a "K-4" base where the meter is bolted into the socket instead of plugging in, or what's called *current transformer* metering, which is what's used in heavy applications but is *totally* different from normal residential self-contained metering

Comment: @user96213 so, what is the 3.5ton AC used for?

Comment: I believe the 3.5 is the second half of the main house - but I may be off on this. We have a/c load calculations for the home, but there are a variety of options (apparently).

Comment: @user96213 -- are they MJ8 load calcs (Manual J, Eighth Edition), or some sort of rule of thumb? they sound awful large for 3500+1000 sqft for a straight MJ8 unless you are living in a glass house...(they're close to the 500sqft/ton "rule of thumb" that was used in the past, but that rule overestimates loads drastically with modern construction practices....)

Comment: @user96213 -- also, where are the air-handlers going to live? it sounds like part of the problem could be the architect oversizing based on faulty (eek! there's a ductopus in the searing hot attic! RUN AWAY!) construction techniques

Comment: Have some [further reading](https://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy10osti/48163.pdf) on why ducts and air-handlers don't belong in vented attics, BTW, and some reading material on the dreaded air-conditioner-eating [ductopus](https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/54332/Release-the-Kraken-The-Ductopus-Is-Bad-for-Air-Conditioning) as well.

Comment: Continuing.... attic is spray foam insulation, a/c and ducts are in conditioned space, home is designed to be energy efficient.... Spoke with a/c contractor and re-looked at load calcs. 200A should be plenty for the main house fed from uppermost 200A breaker. Well house and pool equipment can be fed from onboard buss via 70A breaker, exterior outlet on 20A breaker and sub-1000sq ft guest house fed from buss lugs to 100A panel.... does this sound reasonable in theory and compliant with NEC?

Comment: @user96213 -- updating my answer, it sounds like you're on a far better track :)

Comment: As it relates to energy use and the need for 200A - OR - greater service, are there any recommendations for high efficiency tank-type electric water heaters? [I'd also like to have a hot water circulation loop (with a programmable timer)].

Comment: @user96213 -- yes, there are!  The [Sanden EcoCute HPWHs](https://www.sandenwaterheater.com), while costly upfront ($4k) and requiring a bit more plumbing to install, provide a very high-capacity/high-capability option for efficient hot water.  They do have a couple other downsides as well, primarily in that they require a demand (sensor/aquastat) recirc setup instead of a timer-based one (and lose some efficiency when a recirc setup is present), and some water chemistries void their (otherwise nice) warranty (as they have a SS tank, so acidic or chloride-laden water is no good for them).

Comment: Alternatively, propane is an option; different energy source, but we are considering a propane cook top vs. induction. So, shifting to the plumbing forum with a propane fueled on demand WH system; includes a small tank WH, a programmable circulation pump, and HW loop. Pull in supply HW as needed from the main on-demand unit....???? Are there any electrical concerns to mention about this approach....

Comment: @user96213 -- I would go with the EcoCute in a heartbeat over propane even with the higher upfront costs -- propane is a rather freakishly expensive fuel to burn as you are paying fuel on fuel in order to get it trucked to you, instead of having it shipped in bulk cheaply via pipeline.

Comment: As in Sanden SanCO2? Yes, expensive!

Comment: @user96213 -- yes, but you're looking at only about a 10year payback period for the SanCO2 over a 199kbtu condensing propane tankless if the EnergyGuide labels are anything to go by, so it's probably worth it in your case (esp. since the Sanden will be just going out of its mechanical-parts warranty at that point)

Comment: Very useful information; gives me another product line to consider!

Comment: Going back to the meter base; from the meter socket to the breakers original equipment is 3-0 THW. Is THW mandatory in the breaker side of the panel as well, or is THHN acceptable to connect to the breakers? Is THHN authorized for use throughout the panel both left and right sides? Are there different wire type requirements for the breakers vs. the feed through lugs on the bottom of the buss strips (which could/would feed an adjacent panel on the meter rack)?

Comment: @user96213 -- I added a section to the answer re: feeder wire types and conduit sizing

Comment: All good information on wire size. Back to load centers... if I feed a well house from the meter rack/combo panel (70A breaker) am I required to have a load center with an installed main breaker or NO main breaker installed in the load center? Same goes for the house (200A); main breaker on load center or NO? OR does it all ....matter how its done....?

Answer (score 2):

### That would violate the listing of the equipment

The meter-main you are looking at (the MC0816B1400RLTM) is configured so that the factory-fitted 200A breaker is fitted into the panel interior, with its lugs connected to one of the two sets of jumper wires from the meter base to the breakers, in effect being used as a backfed main for that interior.

Changing this factory configuration would void the equipment's *listing*, which would cause serious AHJ heartburn in just about all cases, and calling UL/ETL/... out to your place for a field examination is generally cost prohibitive for anything that's not a piece of heavy industrial equipment.  So, you can't make the changes you propose.

### However, your concern is addressable in other ways

I would not call your scenario a huge concern in the grand scheme of things, though.  Unless it's the well pump house itself on fire, then the FD can just as easily cut power to individual buildings with your meter-main hardware as they can to the whole lot.  Having a main disconnect for the panel section makes it much easier to work on the equipment safely, as well.

The one caveat, though, is this means that the sub-feed lugs in your meter-main can only be used to subfeed a panel on the meter rack that sources feeders through breakers, not to provide a tap or feeder to a separate structure.  The practical implications of this are that the house cannot have any more than a 200A feeder without restructuring the metering hardware; this is not normally an issue in configurations like this, as long as no massive current hogs such as oversized heat-pump auxiliary heaters or large electric tankless water heaters show up.  (There are better solutions to the problems one would try to solve with such hardware, as well.)

### The resulting configuration

The configuration that results is basically identical to your existing configuration, save for the fact that the 200A panel section is fed via its factory main breaker instead of its lugs, as depicted in your second illustration.  This provides us with two means of disconnect (well within the rule-of-six), and allows for independent shutoff of any of the feeders or loads, as well as a global cutoff for everything aside from the main house.

The bad news, though, is that if the 100A breaker feeds the main house, it would violate NEC 225.30 about the number of supplies to the building.  Having it feed the guest house (ADU) is fine as it would then count under either 225.30(B) point 1 or 225.30(D), but that feeder cannot feed anything in the main house as a result of feeding the ADU, at least under a strict interpretation of NEC 210.25(A).

Since you are able to get the house to run on 200A, though, that means you can go ahead with what you are describing as long as you maintain a strict electrical separation between the circuits for the main house and the circuits for the guest house.  Note that grounds lighting loads cannot be fed from *either* the main house or the guest house under this strict interpretation of 210.25; they would have to be fed either from the pumphouse panel or directly from a breaker in the meter-main.

### Go big or go home!

As to the subpanels involved, there is no reason whatsoever to skimp on them; for a house this size, I would consider a 200A, 42-space, main breaker panel a *bare minimum*, with 54-space or 60-space options readily on the table despite their extra cost over 42-space units.  If space allows, you could even "go for broke" and do *two* 42-space panels (one main breaker, the other main lug) daisy-chained together with a *subfeed lug block* and a short stretch of feeder wiring, giving you 80 spaces for about the same price as 54 or 60 costs.

The pumphouse and guest-house/ADU panels, then, can be 30-space, 125A, main breaker panels; these are relatively inexpensive and provide plenty of room for expansion.  The main breaker, by the way, simply serves as a shutoff in this case, so it can be larger than the feeder breaker in the meter-main without raising any issues.

### As to those feeder wires...

While the factory wiring inside your meter-main is THW, and likely copper as well, this has no bearing on what types of wires are legal to terminate on it in the field; it simply needs to be treated as an integral part of the equipment in this case.  The 20A circuit is probably best run as THHN/THWN in a short conduit (nipple?) run.  However, for large feeders, the wire of choice is XHHW-2 compact stranded aluminum; it's far cheaper than copper at these large sizes, does not pose the hazards that aluminum branch-circuit wires did back in the bad old days, and is more robust to temperature excursions, water, and such than THWN is.

Of course, you need something to protect the wires as they are run underground, and for this we use *conduit*.  In easy soil conditions, PVC can be trenched in to about 22-24" deep and will last basically forever underground.  If trenching is difficult, one can use rigid metal conduit in a 12" trench; this saves a wire in the conduit, at the expense of more work, and some vulnerability to corrosion.  Either way, you want to use *fat* conduits here.  A 3" conduit to the main house would not be at all out of place, if only to leave room for a future upgrade to 400A, and I would run 2" conduits to the guest-house and pumphouse as well if I were in your shoes.

### TORQUE ALL LUGS TO SPEC

One new requirement for the 2017 NEC is found in 110.14(D), and it requires that a calibrated torque tool (wrench or screwdriver) be used on all equipment that has torque values for its screws or lugs labeled on it.  Even if your local authority having jurisdiction does not enforce this, it's still a *very* good idea so that your electrical system doesn't [give you the loose lugnut](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2010/07/16/the-difference-between-success-and-failure-how-a-torque-wrench-improves-system-reliability/).

#### Postscript: What if it turns out the main house *does* need over 200A?

In a case like this where the main house *did* need over 200A, we'd have to turn to a different set of hardware than what you propose in your question, especially given that you have a remotely located meter-main, which takes the typical way it's done (with 2 200A breakers in the meter-main feeding independent subpanels) off the table.

Instead, I would use a 400A meter-loadcenter with a single main breaker, and then use two subfeed lug blocks in parallel to feed a 400A disconnect for the main house. Since breaker coordination is generally not feasible without specific engineering study anyway, you don't lose much by not having a 400A OCPD dedicated to the main house feeder. This also gains you the ability to disconnect the main house without losing power to the pumphouse, or the ADU for that matter, while still having a single "kill all the power" switch available if need be.

If we are to stay with your theme of Siemens hardware, I would go with a MC2442B1400SDL for the meter-main to provide a single main disconnect as well as spaces for the subfeed lugs and the remaining feeder breakers, and a HNF365RA for the disconnect for the main house.  With this, we use a KO punch to put a 2" KO in the bottom of the right side of the meter-main box and the bottom of the left side of the switch enclosure, and connect the pair of ECLK225 subfeed lugs in the main panel to the line lugs on the disconnect switch with a 2" rigid conduit nipple and 4/0 Al wires, two per pole, run lug-to-lug.  The switch also gets a HG656A ground bar kit to provide a place for the feeder EGC to land, by the way, as it needs to have its bonding screw pulled if present.

Comment: ...as in the second photo (factory/existing equipment configuration)...?

Comment: @user96213 -- you do have the equipment configured correctly in the second photo

Comment: 1st pic is "photoshopped", 2nd is factory with photoed in breakers... got the pics online...

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any issues with this setup?

The NEC allows up to six service main breakers for each service. So given your description of what you intend to do *it is allowable by code but with exceptions.*

The most important one is the equipment you are using must be approved as service entrance equipment, and the main design of this equipment requires it to **accept no more than 6 means of disconnect.**

Now this requirement can get kind of tricky and it can generate a lot of discussion, but to keep it simple. You need to address your question to your local AHJ. Even though everything I just said was per the NEC it is a continuing discussion even among inspectors as to what is allowed in a noncommercial single family dwelling unit. The problem for the DIY is whether or not this equipment can be bought *off the self.*

If this is a commercial building or a multiple dwelling unit for something like a apartment rentals. Then the rules are clearly defined and the electrical contractor can easily have one manufactured.

Hope this helps.